PDF Page properties using Gotenberg Python requests
I'm trying to convert word documents and excel documents using the Gotenberg API documentation which only provides cURLs, but I managed to convert the basic cURL using python requests, but cannot seem to incorporate the "Page Properties" parameters into the request as well.
This works:
response = requests.post('https://demo.gotenberg.dev/forms/libreoffice/convert', files={'file': open("FILE", "rb")})

However, I tried several variations of Eg. "scale": "0.5" and "singlePage": "true" using the requests "data" and "params" parameters and they don't seem to be changing the PDF view
response = requests.post('https://demo.gotenberg.dev/forms/libreoffice/convert', files={'file': open("FILE", "rb")}, data={"singlePage" :"true"})
Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks.

Looking at the documentation, the LibreOffice converter accepts only 3 parameters: https://gotenberg.dev/docs/routes#page-properties-libreoffice

@AndrejKesely ahh okay that seems to be it, so the extra parameters are supposed to go into the "data" and not "params" parameters of the request right?
